# How to make sure that original file and gzipped version are not the same

Tags: bash, gzip

My test equipment generates large text files which tend to grow in size over a period of several days as data is added.

But the text files are transferred to a PC for backup purposes *daily*, where they're compressed with `gzip`, even before they've finished growing.

This means I frequently have both `file.txt` and a compressed form `file.txt.gz` where the uncompressed file *may* be more up to date than the compressed version.

I decide which to keep with the following `bash` script `gzandrm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Given an uncompressed file, look in the same directory for 
# a gzipped version of the file and delete the uncompressed 
# file if zdiff reveals they're identical. Otherwise, the 
# file can be compressed.

# eg:  find . -name '*.txt' -exec gzandrm {} \;

if [[ -e $1 && -e $1.gz ]] 
then

    # simple check: use zdiff and count the characters
    DIFFS=$(zdiff "$1" "$1.gz" | wc -c)

    if [[ $DIFFS -eq 0 ]] 
    then

        # difference is '0', delete the uncompressed file
        echo "'$1' already gzipped, so removed"
        rm "$1"

    else

        # difference is non-zero, check manually
        echo "'$1' and '$1.gz' are different"

    fi

else
    # go ahead and compress the file
    echo "'$1' not yet gzipped, doing it now"
    gzip "$1"
fi
```

and this has worked well, but it would make more sense to compare the modification dates of the files, since `gzip` does not change the modification date when it compresses, so two files with the same date are really the same file, even if one of them is compressed.

How can I modify my script to compare files by *date*, rather than *size*?

Comment: The overhead of uncompressing to compare is about the same as compressing again. Why not just compress the text version if it exists and then drop the original in favor of the compressed version all the time?

Comment: Because I don't want to *assume* the text version is always better. In rare cases the text version is a new file, not the old file with text appended.

Comment: If it's a new file shouldn't it have a new name? Couldn't some files actually get smaller?

Comment: The filename is fixed since it defines the contents. Sometimes the operators of the equipment have to repeat the tests with the same name and sometimes delete files to save disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the goal is, but it seems to be simple efficiency, so I think you should make two changes: 1) check modification times, as you suggest, and don't bother comparing content if the uncompressed file is no newer than the compressed file, and 2) use `zcmp` instead of `zdiff`.

Taking #2 first, your script does this:

```
DIFFS=$(zdiff "$1" "$1.gz" | wc -c)
if [[ $DIFFS -eq 0 ]]
```

which will perform a full diff of potentially large files, count the characters in diff's output, and examine the count. But all you really want to know is whether the content differs. `cmp` is better for that, since it will scan byte by byte and stop if it encounters a difference. It doesn't take the time to format a nice textual comparison (which you will mostly ignore); its exit status tells you the result. `zcmp` isn't quite as efficient as raw `cmp`, since it'll need to do an uncompress first, but `zdiff` has the same issue.

So you could switch to `zcmp` (and remove the use of a subshell, eliminate `wc`, not invoke `[[`, and avoid putting potentially large textual diff data into a variable) just by changing the above two lines to this:

```
if zcmp -s "$1"    # if $1 and $1.gz are the same
```

To go a step further and check modification times first, you can use the `-nt` (newer than) option to the `test` command (also known as square bracket), rewriting the above line as this:

```
if [ ! "$1" -nt "$1.gz" ] || zcmp -s "$1"
```

which says that if the uncompressed version is no newer than the compressed version OR if they have the same content, then $1 is already gzipped and you can remove it. Note that if the uncompressed file is no newer, `zcmp` won't run at all, saving some cycles.

The rest of your script should work as is.

One caveat: modification times are very easy to change. Just moving the compressed file from one machine to another could change its modtime, so you'll have to consider your own case to know whether the modtime check is a valid optimization or more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, that gives me a lot of things to try. I use FTP to transfer the files, so modification times don't change and it remains a valid comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an easy to compare date stamp of a file using `stat` with either the `%Y` or `%Z` format strings to get the time of last modification or change in seconds from epoch.

```
if [ $(stat -c %Z $1) -eq ($stat -c %Z $1.gz) ]; then
    echo "Last changed time of $1 is the same as $1.gz"
fi
```

Comment: That's very interesting, but since the uncompressed file may be a new file with a later date, I may have to combine tests for size **and** time.

Comment: Your use case is wacky (reusing example file names for different data sets?), but if you do combine these tests make sure save computation time by running the time test first and only checking size if they are different.

Comment: Excellent idea about checking time *first*, but the realities of production mean that we sometimes just have to start again generating data with the same filename. The later data set *replaces* the first (faulty) data set.

Comment: If the later data set replaces the earlier data set even if it is smaller, why do you need to compare size at all? If the uncompressed time-stamp is newer than the compressed (Use `-gt` in the test above) then it needs to be re-compressed.

Comment: The later data set may start small but grow over time. But yes, the newer data will usually reach the size of the old data and may surpass it, if it doesn't stop short because it's a partial retest (in which case we need to preserve old and new data). I think I should take the view that I can't guarantee preservation of *all* data -- some old data *may* be deleted.